# Python ran from command line runs version 3.6 while in my files it runs version 3.4

Tags: python, pandas, environment-variables, python-3.6, python-3.4

So I have 2 versions of python on my machine, one located at: # python 3.4

```
c:/Python34
```

other located at: # python 3.6

```
c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32
```

The python 3.6 version has all the libraries I would like to use, however when I try to run my python scripts I get errors saying the module doesn't exist.

[image: ImportError: no module named 'pandas']

Now if i run python though the command line like this it works fine.

[image: Now if i run python though the command line like this it works fine.]

So I would like to force my scripts to run though the version where I have all the libraries downloaded.

In my path I have.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher;
```

So when I run my program in the command line I would like it to run using the correct version of python I don't know why its using the other one and it's driving me nutz!

I've uninstalled and reinstalled pandas and numpy with pip install and pip uninstall

I've switched the environment variables to point to Python34 in my command line and attempted to install pandas on that but it was too painful.

I'm writing the code in Sublime Text and running it though the command line just by typing

```
examplecode.py
```

When i run

```
assoc.py
```

and

```
ftype Python.file
```

[i get theses messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwPB2.png)

Comment: First, is this a single-user machine, and do you actually need Python 3.4? Because the easiest solution, if it's appropriate, is to just uninstalled Python 3.4. There's no chance of which-Python-installation confusion like this when you've only got one Python installation.

Comment: If you really need both environments, have a look at [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). It makes maintaining multiple environments quite easy.

Comment: It sounds like a file association issue. Can you post the result of running these on the command line: `assoc .py` and `ftype Python.File`?

Comment: This is a work machine, and im not comfortable deleting anything, so my plan is just to install virtualenv and create an environment with what i need for this project.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed simply by creating a virtual environment with the libraries i needed.

Thanks to ascripter for the advice.

I would have rather just deleted the python 3.4 however this isnt my machine so i don't want to make any waves. good suggestion abarnert!